# Groovy: java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting to find integer on stack

Tags: java, groovy

when I want to migrate **java geohash code** to **groovy platform**, then it report

```
ERROR: Groovy: java.lang.VerifyError: (class: GeoHash, method: 
recombineLatLonBitsToHash signature: (Ljava/lang/Object;[J)LGeoHash;) 
Expecting to find integer on stack
```

this is the java geohash code:

```
protected GeoHash recombineLatLonBitsToHash(long[] latBits, long[] lonBits) {
    GeoHash hash = new GeoHash();
    boolean isEvenBit = false;
    latBits[0] <<= (MAX_BIT_PRECISION - latBits[1]);
    lonBits[0] <<= (MAX_BIT_PRECISION - lonBits[1]);
    double[] latitudeRange = [-90.0, 90.0];
    double[] longitudeRange = [-180.0, 180.0];

    for (int i = 0; i < latBits[1] + lonBits[1]; i++) {
        if (isEvenBit) {
            divideRangeDecode(hash, latitudeRange, (latBits[0] & FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED) == FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED);
            latBits[0] <<= 1;
        } else {
            divideRangeDecode(hash, longitudeRange, (lonBits[0] & FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED) == FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED);
            lonBits[0] <<= 1;
        }
        isEvenBit = !isEvenBit;
    }
    hash.bits <<= (MAX_BIT_PRECISION - hash.significantBits);
    setBoundingBox(hash, latitudeRange, longitudeRange);
    hash.point = hash.boundingBox.getCenterPoint();
    return hash;
}

public GeoHash getSouthernNeighbour() {
    long[] latitudeBits = getRightAlignedLatitudeBits();
    long[] longitudeBits = getRightAlignedLongitudeBits();
    latitudeBits[0] -= 1;
    latitudeBits[0] = maskLastNBits(latitudeBits[0], latitudeBits[1]);
    return recombineLatLonBitsToHash(latitudeBits, longitudeBits);
}
```

then I change the **recombineLatLonBitsToHash** parameters type **long[]** to **def**, it doesn't report error:

```
protected GeoHash recombineLatLonBitsToHash(def latBits, def lonBits) {
    GeoHash hash = new GeoHash();
    boolean isEvenBit = false;
    latBits[0] <<= (MAX_BIT_PRECISION - latBits[1]);
    lonBits[0] <<= (MAX_BIT_PRECISION - lonBits[1]);
    double[] latitudeRange = [-90.0, 90.0];
    double[] longitudeRange = [-180.0, 180.0];

    for (int i = 0; i < latBits[1] + lonBits[1]; i++) {
        if (isEvenBit) {
            divideRangeDecode(hash, latitudeRange, (latBits[0] & FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED) == FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED);
            latBits[0] <<= 1;
        } else {
            divideRangeDecode(hash, longitudeRange, (lonBits[0] & FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED) == FIRST_BIT_FLAGGED);
            lonBits[0] <<= 1;
        }
        isEvenBit = !isEvenBit;
    }
    hash.bits <<= (MAX_BIT_PRECISION - hash.significantBits);
    setBoundingBox(hash, latitudeRange, longitudeRange);
    hash.point = hash.boundingBox.getCenterPoint();
    return hash;
}

public GeoHash getSouthernNeighbour() {
    long[] latitudeBits = getRightAlignedLatitudeBits();
    long[] longitudeBits = getRightAlignedLongitudeBits();
    latitudeBits[0] -= 1;
    latitudeBits[0] = maskLastNBits(latitudeBits[0], latitudeBits[1]);
    return recombineLatLonBitsToHash(latitudeBits, longitudeBits);
}
```

I want to know why the error is reported and why I change the type to def then work. thx!

Comment: What version of Groovy and Java... this does not usually happen on current versions.

Comment: @cjstehno Groovy 2.4.4, Java 8

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this is a Java class that you are trying to call from Groovy code?

Comment: @Ruraj Not exactly, I move the Java class code to run on Groovy platform. That is copying Java code onto groovy platform and try to run it